# Array - grab all field items independent of level

Tags: javascript, arrays, flat

Let's assume I have an array such as this here:

```js
const data = {
  id: "helloworld",
  type: "Collection",
  _embedded: {
    items: [{
        fields: [{
          id: "bla",
          fields: [{
            id: "nice",
            value: 100
          }]
        }, {
          id: "no",
          fields: [{
            id: "js",
            value: true
          }]
        }]

      },
      {
        fields: [{
          id: "od",
          fields: [{
            id: "adeb",
            value: 456
          }]
        }, {
          id: "def",
          fields: [{
            id: "frft",
            value: 77
          }]
        }]

      }

    ]
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve:

-Get a flattened list of all items that are in **fields** arrays. So in the end I need to have a list with every item that was in a fields array.
-The solution should be independend of levels. So it should go deeper and deeper to really find all items of **fields** arrays.

At the moment we have:

```js
const flattenedProductFieldsList = data?._embedded?.items
        .flat(2)
        .map((el) => el.fields)
        .filter((el) => el)
        .flat(2)
        .map((el) => el._embedded)
        .filter((el) => el)
        .flat(2)
        .filter((el) => el)
        .map((el) => el.items)
        .filter((el) => el)
        .flat(2)
        .map((el) => el.fields)
        .filter((el) => el)
        .flat(2);
```

But this of course is bad, because we are limited to a specific level of hierarchy. Moreover this flattening is not nice at all.

Is there a good solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a recursive function. Since you haven't specified anything about a specific order it might fit your need. For huge datasets this might give issues though.

```
const result = [];

function extract(dataSet)
     dataSet.forEach(elem => {
         if (Object.keys(elem).includes("fields")) {
             extract(elem.fields);
         }
         if (Object.keys(elem).includes("value")) {
             result.push(elem.value);
         }
     }
}

extract(data._embedded.items);
console.log(result);
```

I've only added the `value` part of each level in the result array but you can extend this will include all required data.